# Counting top repeated lines in log

Tags: linux, algorithm, bash, counting

Reading the title will lead you to think, I saw this question a hundred times, and you did, but I'm looking for something different:

The common answer is

```
sort <input> | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

But when the input is tens of millions of lines, sort becomes impractical. Sort is an O(n log(n)) algorithm.It can be palatalized, but it still requires O(n) amount of memory.

I am looking for an algorithm that can do this counting much better: using the following assumptions: the number of types of log messages is much smaller then the log files (thousands). I am interested in the top 50 recurring messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to implement a simple type of bucket sort:

```
awk 'a[$0]++; END {for (line in a) { print a[line], line; }}' |  sort -k1,1nr | head -50
```

The `awk` command counts occurrences of each unique line and outputs each line with its count, in O(n) time. The `sort` then simply sorts the output by count in reverse numerical order, and `head` outputs the 50 largest.